how to blur up sensitive information on questions or answers?
as it was just recently the case on this question of mine - I want to show the result of a query, but I cannot show server names and other specific properties that would potentially cause harm.
however, I enjoy details and clarity, my question is:
visually the way I did - blurring all with red on top of the info I did not want to show - is horrendous - is there a way or couple of ways I could have done that in a nicer way?
this is not a shopping list question, however, do we have a standard way or a free tool to get this done?


I use the freeware greenshot (HT @Zikato) and recommend it for formal screencap markup.

In the specific example you give though, you could also just drag the column to minimum width to hide the data or off to the far righthand side of the resultset (if for some reason it's untenable to reorder the resultset or remove entirely the sensitive column from the query) as seen here.

thats way better visually and does the job
